# Calling function from DevTools console does not trigger breakpoint

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints, google-chrome-console

My Chrome DevTools pauses at a breakpoint I set.

I go to the console, and I manually call a function (say, `myFunc()`) and it executes properly.

However, the breakpoint I set inside `myFunc()` is never hit! I expect that when I call the function, the function in the code should be called and the breakpoint should be hit!

The source code is extremely simple:

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';

// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>TypeScript Starter</h1>`;

appDiv.__proto__.myFunc = function(){
  var myCoolFunction = "My cool function"; //. <---- breakpoint on this line is never hit
  console.log('myCoolFunction:', myCoolFunction);
}
console.log('appDiv', appDiv); // <---- manually call appDiv.myFunc() while paused on this line
```

Here is the link to the page: https://typescript-gmngl3.stackblitz.io/~/index.ts

Link to source code in Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gmngl3

Screenshot:

[image: Stackblitz console]

Comment: FYI: put `debug` if your braikpoint fails to work

Comment: like Justinas said use debugger: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger 
right where the breakpoint is, you should be able to access the function then

Comment: Thanks! But question still stands, why isn't it hitting the breakpoint? It's a pain to go in and put `debugger` and then recomplile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are paused at a breakpoint on line 12 in the screenshot, and you're trying to call the function from there. Since the debugger is already paused there, my guess *('guess', since I am not familiar with the internals of the debugger)* is that it cannot jump to any other breakpoint without using the debugger controls.

A suggested workaround:
When the debugger pauses on line 12, assign the reference of `appDiv` to a new variable in the console:

```js
savedAppDiv = appDiv
```

Then continue and let the script run entirely. After that, you can use the stored reference to call `myFunc` and it should pause at the breakpoint within it:

```js
savedAppDiv.myFunc()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call debug(function) in your console, and it should add a breakpoint on the first line on your function. Here are some more details: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#function

In your case, write this into console:

```js
debug(appDiv.myFunc);

// now you can call myFunc and it should hit a breakpoint

appDiv.myFunc()
```